# Not able to remove NaN from ruby array

Tags: ruby

I have an array of values

```
=> [0.0, 4.76, 0.0, Infinity, NaN, 2.63, 0.74, 10.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, Infinity, 5.26, NaN, 0.0, NaN, 3.45, 2.5, NaN, 10.0, 0.0, NaN, 2.94, NaN, NaN, 0.0, 2.04, 0.0, 11.11, NaN, NaN, 1.23, NaN, NaN, 11.11, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.0, 9.68, NaN, NaN, 10.0, 5.0, 3.7, 10.0, Infinity, 0.0, 0.0, 1.41, NaN, 3.45, NaN]
```

When I run this script to remove NaN's it removes some but not all NaN's.

```
  def remove_from_array(numArray)
    numArray.inject(0) do |i|
      if numArray[i].nan?
        numArray.delete_at(i)
      end
      i += 1
    end
   numArray
  end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than try to remove them, modify your code so you don't generate them. Use `select` or `reject` to pre-test for values that result in NaN.

Comment: Insert `p "num_array=#{num_array}"` before `if numArray..` to see what's going on. Do you mean `"NaN"` or `:Nan`? As written, `Nan` is the value of a constant or the value returned by a method of that name. If, as I suspect, `Nan` is a literal, please edit. Incidentally, in Ruby it is customary to use "snake-case" (all lowercase letters and underscores) for the names of variables and methods (e.g., `num_array`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you delete an item *and* move to the next index, you’re moving two items ahead, because the item at the current index no longer exists.

Luckily, there’s a better way, using [`Array#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
numArray.reject! &:nan?
```